# Count > 1 for distinct rows with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

My data is like

HRS -  SVDATE

1 - 1/1/2017

1 -     1/1/2017

1 -     2/1/2017

2 -     1/1/2017

2 -     1/1/2017

2 -     1/1/2017

3 -     3/1/2017

4 -     1/1/2017

4 -     2/1/2017

4 -     3/1/2017

forgive me i am using aiphen(-)between columns

Here i need to get distinct records of HRS and SVDATE with count> 2
like below only below rows i want

HRS -    SVDATE

1 -      1/1/2017

1 -      2/1/2017

4 -      1/1/2017

4 -      2/1/2017

4 -      3/1/2017

I tried using using Group by HRS,SVDATE HAVING COUNT(hrs) >1

I am  getting for HRS=1 count=3  but i need for HRS=1 count=2(here only two distict SVDATE's are there)

please help how to write query for this

Comment: why is `2 - 1/1/2017`not in your expected result ?

Comment: Not clear to me.  VTC

Answer (score 1):

Your `COUNT(hrs)` just counts the number of records for which `hrs` is non-`NULL`.

You need `COUNT(DISTINCT hrs)` instead:

```
SELECT
 svdate,
 COUNT(DISTINCT hrs) AS NrOfDistinctHours,
 COUNT(*)            AS NrOfRows
FROM ...
GROUP BY svdate
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT hrs) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly it will give the output which you are looking for

```
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.svdate,t1.hrs from table t1 
          JOIN (SELECT hrs from
                 (SELECT DISTINCT svdate,hrs FROM table)
                GROUP BY hrs
                HAVING COUNT(hrs) > 1) t2 
           ON t1.hrs=t2.hrs
```